# how to make a slideshow repeat using javascript

Tags: javascript, slideshow

ok my slideshow is my body background and the imgs are in img tags like this

```
 <img name="pic" src="../../Content/images/bg.jpg" style="  width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1;width: expression(document.body.clientWidth + 'px');   " alt=""/>
```

my problem is it plays but then stops on the last image instead of being continuous

also how would i implement a stop play prev next button a the top of the page that also controls the background 
i dont want to download no plugins if possible
thanks

here is my code so far

```
  var pause = 3000;

var n = 0;

var imgs = new Array("bg.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg", "bg4.jpg", "bg5.jpg", "bg6.jpg", "bg7.jpg", "bg8.jpg", "bg9.jpg", "bg10.jpg", "bg11.jpg");


var preload = new Array();
for (var i = 1; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    preload[i] = new Image();
    preload[i].src = imgs[i];
}

var inc = -1

function rotate() {

    document.images.pic.src = imgs[n];
    (n == (imgs.length - 1)) ? n = 0 : n++;
    setTimeout("rotate(0)", pause);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this?

```
n = ( n==imgs.length-1 ? 0 : n+1);
```

Comment: still doesnt work firebug says missing ) in parenthetical when i use that

Comment: You could try rearranging it as if/else... "if(n==imgs.length-1) n=0 else n++;"

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring your code like this:

```
var i, imgs, pic;

function rotate()
{
  pic.src = imgs[i] ;
  (i === (imgs.length -1) ) ? i=0 : i++ ;
  setTimeout( rotate, 5000 ); 
}

function init()
{
  pic = document.getElementById("pic");

  imgs = ["bg.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg"] ;

  var preload= new Array();
  for( i=0; i< imgs.length; i++ )
  {
    preload[ i ] = new Image();
    preload[ i ].src = imgs[ i ];
  }

  i=0;

  rotate();
}
onload=init;
```

And in your html page you could have something like this:

```
<img id="pic" width="960" height="300" alt="Icon" src="bg1.jpg">
```